# Jitsi call disconnect after dial in android

Tags: android-studio, voip, openfire, jitsi, lib-jitsi-meet

I am using openfire and I wanted to add voice and video call feature in my app.
First I have made installed two plugins ofmeet.jar and offocus.jar.

Then I have installed lets encrypt wild card certificate in openfire.
ex:

```
/snap/bin/certbot certonly --dns-route53 -d example.com,*.example.com
```

Installed those generated certificate in openfire by admin dashboard panel.

created a subdomain openfire.example.com to point with VPS IP address.
however my FQDN is example.com.

added code in android to start meeting

```
try {
JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder options = new JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder()
.setServerURL(new URL(“https://openfire.example.com”))
.setRoom(“testroom”)
.setWelcomePageEnabled(false);

        JitsiMeetActivity.launch(OutGoingMeetingInvitation.this, options.build());
        finish();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Am getting error in android phones that am disconnected and reconnecting in seconds.
In android studio I am getting error

```
E/JitsiMeetSDK: [features/base/lib-jitsi-meet] Failed to load config from https://call.example.com/config.js?room=call_1606192562839 Error(AbortError){“message”:“Aborted”,“stack”:“Error: Aborted\n at anonymous (index.android.bundle:135:6514)\n at anonymous (index.android.bundle:135:7422)\n at call (native)\n at dispatchEvent (index.android.bundle:126:5676)\n at value (index.android.bundle:121:5993)\n at value (index.android.bundle:121:5621)\n at l (index.android.bundle:135:6840)\n at call (native)\n at dispatchEvent (index.android.bundle:144:5676)\n at value (index.android.bundle:143:1114)\n at anonymous (index.android.bundle:876:490)\n at anonymous (index.android.bundle:399:500)\n at apply (native)\n at value (index.android.bundle:50:1280)\n at apply (native)\n at value (index.android.bundle:37:3685)\n at anonymous (index.android.bundle:37:841)\n at value (index.android.bundle:37:2939)\n at value (index.android.bundle:37:813)”}
I/JitsiMeetSDK: [features/overlay] The conference will be reloaded after 11 seconds.
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be because of External ports. Enabling **UDP port** in server resolved this issue for me, in your server make sure below ports are enabled,

- 80/tcp for Web UI HTTP (really just to redirect, after uncommenting ENABLE_HTTP_REDIRECT=1 in .env)
- 443/tcp for Web UI HTTPS
- 4443/tcp for RTP media over TCP
- 10000/udp for RTP media over UDP

https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/devops-guide/devops-guide-docker

**with Ubuntu**

- 80 TCP - for SSL certificate verification / renewal with Let's Encrypt
- 443 TCP - for general access to Jitsi Meet
- 10000 UDP - for general network video/audio communications
- 22 TCP - if you access you server using SSH (change the port accordingly if it's not 22)
- 3478 UDP - for querying the stun server (coturn, optional, needs config.js change to enable it)
- 5349 TCP - for fallback network video/audio communications over TCP (when UDP is blocked for example), served by coturn

More information [here](https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/devops-guide/devops-guide-quickstart)